# Panda iloc only returns header row and first value row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, slice

Even removing the iloc doesn't  work. I have tried importing it into a CSV file but it doesn't fix the problem. The other tables on `the link` don't seem to have the same problem as this one graph. When I run this right now, instead of getting 30 data rows, I only get 2.

Here's the code:

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import lxml


#makes terminal larger to see full table
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

#specify the url
quote_page = 'https://ysx-mm.com/main-board/listing/company/lc00001/'

#makes it into a dataframe
dfs = pd.read_html(quote_page)
df = dfs[2]
ds = df.iloc[0:30, 0:5]
print(ds)

#exports as a csv file
ds.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change to this:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(quote_page, header =0, flavor = 'bs4')
```

then your code return:

```
            Date   Open   High    Low  Close  Trading volume (shares)  Trading value (MMK)  No. of listed Shares  Market Cap. (mil MMK)
0     16 Mar 2021   9300   9300   9300   9300                      554              5152200              33109694                 307920
1     15 Mar 2021   9400   9400   9400   9400                        1                 9400              33109694                 311231
2     12 Mar 2021   9400   9400   9400   9400                      110              1034000              33109694                 311231
3     12 Mar 2021   9400   9400   9400   9400                      110              1034000              33109694                 311231
4     11 Mar 2021   9300   9300   9300   9300                       60               558000              33109694                 307920
5     10 Mar 2021   9400   9400   9400   9400                       30               282000              33109694                 311231
6      9 Mar 2021   9500   9500   9400   9400                       31               294400              33109694                 311231
7      8 Mar 2021   9500   9500   9500   9500                       17               161500              33109694                 314542
8      5 Mar 2021   9300   9300   9300   9300                       49               455700              33109694                 307920
9      4 Mar 2021   9500   9500   9500   9500                       55               522500              33109694                 314542
10     3 Mar 2021   9500   9500   9500   9500                       50               475000              33109694                 314542
11     1 Mar 2021   9500   9500   9500   9500                      791              7514500              33109694                 314542
12    26 Feb 2021   9300   9300   9300   9300                       26               241800              33109694                 307920
13    25 Feb 2021   9300   9300   9300   9300                     1162             10806600              33109694                 307920
14    24 Feb 2021   9200   9300   9200   9300                      311              2872100              33109694                 307920
..................................................
```